# Failed to load layers from WMS server

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to load layers from WMS using QGIS with following adress:

http://bialystok.geoportal2.pl/map/wms/wms.php

I am able to connect to server and see available layers however I cannot load them on the map. I tried to change ESPG or load layers on empty project but still I can't see anything on the map.

Can you please tell me is it possible to load "siec_energetyczna" layer from this WMS and why I can't load the layers?

I saw that connection is working fine on this website: 
http://bialystok.geoportal2.pl/map/www/mapa.php?CFGF=wms&mylayers=%20granice%20OSM

Comment: As well as the fact that some internal URL is advertised in the GetCapabilities response, (which is an error), also take note that the layers are scale layered and particularly `siec_energetyczna` which tells us: `<ScaleHint min="0.141421" max="2.020305"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an *unconventional* WMS server to say the least - when I try to get the capabilities directly it returns a text string but no xml. However, QGIS does some how manage to get a layers listing. **But**, it seems that contains an invalid `getMap` address of `http://podgik-2:83/?` (you can check this in the layer properties metadata) so if you go to your WMS connection and edit it you can tick the `Ignore GetMap/GetTile URI reported in capabilities` and QGIS will work out how to request the layers directly from the same endpoint as the capabilities document and will then display data.